# Using both global and folder `\vars` Jenkins libraries

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I have some global variables in the global `vars` directory, let's call the class `Sys`. I have some Jenkins-folder variables in the folder-level `vars` directory, let's call the class `Vars`. In the global /src directory I have a class called `Utils`.

Questions:

1. How do I reference `Sys` from within `Utils`
2. How do I reference `Sys` from within `Vars`
3. How do I reference `Sys` from within my pipeline code given that I already reference `Vars` using `@Library('globals') _`

Thanks a bunch, `.a.`

Comment: It is very unclear what you are asking. Do you mean "package" or "class" then you say "directory"? Please [edit] this question and make it clear what you want to do, what you have tried, and what results you get.

Comment: @jdv a [Jenkins shared library may contain three directories, `var`, `src`, and `resources`](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/).  Jenkins shared libraries are not required to contain packages or classes, so OP almost certainly does mean "directory".

Comment: Titles and tags are often so useless I didn't even look at them this time. My bad.

Comment: I cannot describe the problem any clearer. The Jenkins library system mandates the use of a /src directory and /vars directory (as well as /resources) to host the .groovy files that make up the libraries...